# Elegant solution to initalize a struct with many fields

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

In my program, I am trying to find an elegant solution to initalize a user struct. The problem I am facing is I have many, many fields which make initalizing the user bulky and messy. There is one thing to note which may be helpful:

1. When a user is first registered to the app, some fields I want to have default values such as a bio, school, ocupation, etc. (because they have not yet had the chance to populate the data)

I have already tried to wrap other structs around the fields to make the class less messy, but still seems to be a terrible work around.

```
public struct User {
    
    //MARK: - Fields

    var email: String
    var userSettings: UserSettings
    var userProfile: UserProfile
    var uid: String
    
    
    init?(with userNode: [String: Any]) {
        
        guard let userProfile = UserProfile(userNode: userNode),
              let userSettings = UserSettings(userNode: userNode),
              let email = userNode[EMAIL] as? String,
              let uid = userNode[UID] as? String else { return nil }
        
        self.userProfile = userProfile
        self.userSettings = userSettings
        self.email = email
        self.uid = uid

    }
    
    /**
        Initalize a new user with credentials. Will initalize user with default settings and profile
     */
    init?(with credentials: AuthCredentials,
          profileDownloadUrl: [String],
          uid: String) {
        
        guard let birthday = credentials.birthday,
              let firstName = credentials.firstName,
              let lastName = credentials.lastName,
              let gender = credentials.gender,
              let preference = credentials.preference,
              let geoHash = credentials.location?.geoHash,
              let latitude = credentials.location?.latitude,
              let longitude = credentials.location?.longitude,
              let email = credentials.email else {
            return nil
        }
        
        //Create default profile
        self.userProfile = UserProfile(birthday: birthday,
                                         profilePictures: profileDownloadUrl,
                                         firstName: firstName,
                                         lastName: lastName)
        //Create default settings
        self.userSettings = UserSettings(minSeekingAge: MAX_AGE,
                                         maxSeekingAge: MIN_AGE,
                                         distanceRange: MAX_DISTANCE_RANGE,
                                         gender: gender,
                                         preference: preference,
                                         geoHash: geoHash,
                                         latitude: latitude,
                                         longitude: longitude)
        
        //Assign email
        self.email = email
        
        //Assign user id
        self.uid = uid

    }

}
```

What is the recomended design pattern to use? I've looked into the builder design pattern, but personally I am not a fan, as I will still have to manually set as many fields.

Comment: I don't quite understand the goal: " as I will still have to manually set as many fields". So are you looking for a way to automatically decode dictionary into struct? Sort of like it would from JSON? If so, you could either convert your dictionaries to JSON, and then use JSON decoder to parse that JSON as your struct. Or even  implement a custom decoder... But as I said, not quite clear on the goal

Comment: "as I will still have to manually set as many fields." So do you expect Swift to read your mind or something? The way that you are setting these fields is non-trivial, with your `init(with:profileDownloadUrl:uid:)` and `init(with:)` initialisers. Swift can't generate these for you. Are you fine with not having these initialisers, and having whatever Swift generates for you instead?

Comment: You can start with some default value given in a static var, eg `User.default`, and then update each field as it is entered.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write the code…

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write the code, but in this case you can write a lot less code with a little bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a lot of code by introducing an `Error` type representing a missing field, and a helper function that throws that error:

```
struct MissingField: Error { }

func missingField<R>() throws -> R { throw MissingField() }
```

With `missingField`, you can rewrite each of your inits along these lines:

```
    init?(userNode: [String: Any]) {
        do {
            userProfile = try UserProfile(userNode: userNode) ?? missingField()
            userSettings = try UserSettings(userNode: userNode) ?? missingField()
            email = try userNode[EMAIL] as? String ?? missingField()
            uid = try userNode[UID] as? String ?? missingField()
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    init?(
        credentials: AuthCredentials,
        profileDownloadUrl: [String],
        uid: String
    ) {
        do {
            userProfile = try UserProfile(
                birthday: credentials.birthday ?? missingField(),
                profilePictures: profileDownloadUrl,
                firstName: credentials.firstName ?? missingField(),
                lastName: credentials.lastName ?? missingField()
            )
            
            userSettings = try UserSettings(
                minSeekingAge: MAX_AGE,
                maxSeekingAge: MIN_AGE,
                distanceRange: MAX_DISTANCE_RANGE,
                gender: credentials.gender ?? missingField(),
                preference: credentials.preference ?? missingField(),
                geoHash: credentials.geoHash ?? missingField(),
                latitude: credentials.latitude ?? missingField(),
                longitude: credentials.longitude ?? missingField()
            )
            
            email = try credentials.email ?? missingField()
            self.uid = uid
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
```